"from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC" raises "ImportError: No module named '_hdfext'" and no one seems to know where "_hdfext" is
My system is Windows and Python3.
I'd like to import pyhdf.SD, and I can import pyhdf successfully.
However, when I run from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC, it raises
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyhdf\hdfext.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1173, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _hdfext: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\__main__.py", line 39, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 284, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name="__main__")
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 321, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 135, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\community\common7\ide\extensions\microsoft\python\core\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 124, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\usrname\source\repos\HDF\HDF\HDF.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pyhdf.SD import SD, SDC
  File "C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyhdf\SD.py", line 1003, in <module>
    from . import hdfext as _C
  File "C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyhdf\hdfext.py", line 17, in <module>
    _hdfext = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyhdf\hdfext.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_hdfext')
  File "C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_hdfext'

I can find those who resolved the same issue however all those solutions are not helpful.
For example, at this forum, the "_hdftext.so" file resolved the "No _hdfext" problem, however no one except the asking question could obtain it.
Besides, I installed
numpy 1.26.4 (not latest because another module requires this)
hdf4lib 4.2.16-2
VisualStudioBuildTool2022
zlib
and They are the requirement for pyhdf which is showed on the official site but I can't install only libjpeg because I don't know how to install it and how it works.
How can I get the missed the "_hdfext" file?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Supplement:the "_hdfext" directory is not same with "hdfext" files such as "hdfext.i".

Where is the HDF4 library stored, and have you adjusted your environment settings as recommended at https://fhs.github.io/pyhdf/install.html?

The HDF4library is installed in C:\Program Files\HDF_Group\HDF
and its path is correctly set.
Besides I don't understand about compiling of C and the libraries required, so although there should be insufficiency in my environment, I have no idea where the problem is.

The key is the two messages ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _hdfext: The specified module could not be found., and ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_hdfext'. So you need to find out where the missing module is.

I found that although the "_hdfext" module should be generated with SWIG automatically when pyhdf module is built, it isn't generated in my environment, and I have no idea to generate it.
Considering that ".so" extension is available only in Linux OS, if I change my environment from Windows to Linux, the file might be generated successfully.

If you have a Linux system available it may be worth a try, but that does not solve the problem for Windows. And according to https://github.com/fhs/pyhdf/issues/6, it seems to be a problem on Linux also.
